# SQLAlchemy check if column contains any substring in an array

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy table called `Player` which has a column `Position`, along with other similar columns for basketball players. Any value within `Position` will either be `Guard`, `Forward`, or `Center`.

Given an array of positions that the user would like to see results for, such as `[Guard, Forward]` or `[Guard]` or `[Forward, Center, Guard]`, I would like to query the `Position` column to see if **any** positions within the array match the row that meets the other criteria the user filtered for, such as age, weight, height, etc.

For example, if the user searched for a Player with filters looking like `age < 30 & position = [Guard,Forward]`, the expected result would be all Players who are under 40 and are guards or fowards.

I am familiar with the `.contains()` method for columns. I was attempting to run something similar to `query.filter(Player.position.contains(positions))` but I was running into issues because `positions` is an array and not a string.

Since there are only 3 possible positions, one really hacky alternative is to do a few if statements that cover every single scenario (1 position in the array, all 3, a certain combo, etc...) but this will be hard to maintain if I had more positions.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `_in` seems to work for this. `query.filter(Player.position.in_(positions))` gave me the expected result. had to play around with case sensitivity